# Declaractions and constants

Tags: vba

A lot of my files needs to be saved with a specific date. I have written an inputbox so the user inputs this date which is then going to be applied to the workbook names/sheet names etc. Is there a way to set this in the declaration as a constant so the user only has to input this once? The same date will be applied in several macros in several different modules.

I'm thinking something to do with constants and declarations. But const doesn't allow me to use an Inputbox.

Comment: You should use a regular variable instead of a constant.

Answer (score 1):

In a module declare it as a global

```
Global save_date as String
```

and the assign it once

```
save_date = ...
```

Comment: `Global` isn't an official VBA keyword. I think it's there for backward compatibility with some antique version of Basic. Should probably use `Public` instead.

Comment: I have the official VBA reference book and it is in there. It says to use `Public` in classes and `Global` in modules.

Comment: Ha, I wonder why it isn't in the [online documentation.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278949%28v=office.14%29.aspx) Someone must be lying!! :-)